# Approaches to smoothing 3D rotations between orientation updates?

Tags: 3d, processing.js

I'm building a 3D visualizer in Processing.js with python that visualizes the orientation of an object in space in realtime.

The problem is, the sensor I'm using to check the object orientations has a low refresh rate.

So I need to create a way to "smooth" the transition from one orientation to the next - gradually rotating the virtual object from its previous orientation to its next in 'n number of steps', by the shortest possible, overall rotation.

The sensor outputs orientation in the format of a Euler vector

---

From searching around, I've been confused with many different approaches to this from using/converting to and from quaternions, rotational matrices or computing the angle-axis rotations, etc...

**Not asking for the solution, rather, what is the best approach I should use to achieve this effect?**

Comment: Since you've brushed up against quaternions on your search, I would recommend [Slerp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp) - Spherical linear (quaternion) interpolation. Of course, this requires a working knowledge of quaternions - but you can probably find library code that does the heavy lifting.

Comment: hmmm I looked into it a little bit, in this post - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2975109/how-to-convert-euler-angles-to-quaternions-and-get-the-same-euler-angles-back-fr - the responder says that this conversion fails in certain cases and the only way to ensure accurate conversion is the restrict the axis domain. This seems to be the same problem as the gimbal lock. Is there no way that works 100% in every case? Is this method most computationally efficient? @BrettHale

Comment: Please don't start this using Processing.js - it was discontinued in December of 2018 (and already out of feature support for years by then), and you are _far_ better off using something that's actually maintained, like p5js or even something "not Processing based". Having said that... what's "processing.js with python"? Those are incompatible technologies.